# C# clickonce to UWP desktop bridge

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

Hi I have a Visual Studio C# windows forms click once application. I would like to know how to convert it into UWP desktop bridge so it's visible in windows store.

Is there any example that I can look at?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source for the application, it is better to build a package using the Windows App Packaging Project in Visual Studio. Here's a link to the docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net

-Adam Braden [MS]

Answer (score 0):

You can manually convert your app installer to a packaged app and use the Desktop Bridge.

Here's how: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-manual-conversion

If your click once app is unpacking any files to any specific folders, you need to make sure the unpacked files are included in the package (either under VFS or in the root).